# Свой доверенный корневой сертификат

Tags: google-chrome, openssl

Потребовалось мне выпустить свой корневой сертификат для подписи сертификатов компании. Так как я делал это раньше (последний раз году в 2015), то не ожидал подвоха.

Первое, что меня ожидало: теперь обязательно нужно в subkectAltNames указывать домены. Иначе google chorme не признает такой сертификат. 
Второе: при подписывании CA ключем терялась информация из X509_Extension. Это тоже решил добавлением ключа -extension при подписи.

Далее сертификаты заработали в MacOS и Windows. Но ubuntu пошла каким-то своим путем. Как я не старался, не смог добавить свой сертификат в доверенные.

Что я сделал 
Скопировал свой сертификат в /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra
Запустил `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` и `update-ca-certificates`. Импортировал в google chrome. Замочек всегда красный.

Выпускал с разными настройками. Не помогает.

Раньше все работало даже вот по [этой](https://habr.com/post/192446/) статье. Сейчас нет (даже в Mac).

Сейчас я использовал статьи:
http://pavelruban.org/kak-sdelat-svoy-sertifikat-ssl-doverennym
http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=194259.0

Парень с форума даже сделал сервак для проверки http://ca.rootdir.org
Якобы если импортнуть его корневой, то замочек должен стать зеленым.

Но ожидаемо в google chrome видим "Издатель неизвестен".

Очень прошу помочь понять, как сделать свой CA сертификат доверенным в ubuntu.

[image: Пример работы на MacOS]

Comment: да дистрибутив-то тут при чём? проблемы у вас с гуглом и его проприетарной программой chrome.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ни одна из программ ubuntu не доверяет этому "доверенному сертификату". При просмотре сертификата я вижу фразу "Неизвестный издатель" после добавления в хранилище. Я допускаю что в конфиге у меня при генерации что-то не так указано. Вопрос собственно в том, что нужно сделать, чтобы ubuntu стал доверять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl)

Пошаговая инструкция [здесь](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/generate-self-signed-certificates.html)